# A good reference for Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What are the best references for Oracle PL/SQL? I have an excellent knowlege of SQL-92 and of MS-SQL extensions, but now I'm working with Oracle and I'm struggling to find good references for the PL/SQL language.

I am looking for references for the following:

- Variable
- Loops
- Cursor
- Packages
- Trigger
- Stored Procedures
- Temporary Tables

Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their time and their links

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Klaus says the online documentation is pretty good.  Start with the [2-Day Application Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/toc.htm).  If you're using 11gR2, you'll want to read the most recent version of the [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm). Newer Oracle releases have updated versions of the documents.

But if you want to buy a book, then Steven Feuerstein's [Oracle PL/SQL Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024859.do) is the one.

Comment: That's a good book, as a bonus if you're going to purchase at Oreilly.com, using coupon code LREL40 gives you a 40%

Comment: Feuerstein is definitely the guru when it comes to PL/SQL

Comment: I learned PL/SQL out of that book.  Well worth the investment.

Answer (score 7):

One additional observation.  You include temporary tables in a list of PL/SQL features.  This is because you are used to the T-SQL way of doing things.  In Oracle things are handled differently.

In Oracle we have global temporary tables.  These are *permanent* database objects, like regular tables, but they are defined so that the data is held temporarily - either for the duration of a transaction or a session.  The data in a global temporary table is only queryable by the session which populates it.

The point being that temporary tables are discussed in [the SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#i2153132), not the PL/SQL manual.

Answer (score 2):

[This reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/toc.htm) is really good.

Comment: Or for latest version (11.2): http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/toc.htm

Answer (score 2):

In addition to PL/SQL documentation that others have mentioned, the [Oracle Database Concepts Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/toc.htm) is a good reference for finding out how Oracle works, including an overview of package, triggers, tables etc. I have posted a link to the 11.2 version, but you can find the docs for older versions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I've always found [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/index.php) to be good quick reference

Comment: Nicly indexed quick reference, not very in depth though.

Answer (score 0):

Java2s has a good reference tutorial.

Here is the Oracle section:  http://www.java2s.com/Book/Oracle/CatalogOracle.htm

Here is the Oracle PL/SQL reference catalog, easy to navigate:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/CatalogOracle.htm

Here is the Oracle PL/SQL tutorial section:  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/CatalogOracle.htm

I have the OReilly Book but won't post where I got that link along with Oracle Student workbook which is on Scribd.

And along with the Oracle references and tahiti oracle, this site was a good tutorial site for beginners.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Adding points to accepted answer:

- 1)[Concepts for Database Developers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/title.htm)
- 2) [Temporary tables in stored procedure from AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1164655862293)
   Sample code snippet from AskTom
  open ref_cursor for 
  select * 
  from ( query you used to put into temp_1 ), 
  ( query you used to put into temp_2 ) 
  where join_conditions

in your procedure. You'll find that Oracle is much better at complex queries involving dozens (yes more then 16) tables -- without any issues whatsoever.