# A good reference for Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A good reference for Oracle PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041879/a-good-reference-for-oracle-pl-sql)

I need make a procedure to fill some tables in oracle, i'm new in oracle, i need receive two ids, with that make a couple of loops, iteratos, or something like that, and then make a few of sql, the procedure will be called into a trigger, but i can't find a good and complete reference to PL/SQL, suggestions?

Comment: Loops inside a trigger? Alarms bells are going off inside my head. After you get your head around PL/SQL and finish writing your sproc, I strongly suggest you come back to SO to have it reviewed.

Comment: The two ids are from two tables, i need a kind of cartesian product of that tables for make inserts in another table, maybe, you're rigth and i can do that with only a couple of sql sentences without the loop.

Comment: I agree with Marcelo, a trigger seems like the wrong approach for this sort of thing.  Triggers are the wrong approach for most of the things for which they get used.  Post another question explaining what you need to do (i.e. business logic) and we can help you with the best way of implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's own website has extensive documentation, both online and PDF. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/toc.htm) for 11g's online SQL reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: [PL/SQL for Application Developers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_part_plsql.htm#CHDGEBHI)